# Adding unknown count of values inside a SELECT statement

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have code that adds a value inside a SQL table :

```
SqlCommand command;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
String strSQL = "";

strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblTest (value1) VALUES ('" + strPLCData + "')";
   
command = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cnn);
adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cnn);

try
{
    int rows = adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    txtStatusLogging.Text += "Inserted " + rows + " row(s) in the database." + Environment.NewLine;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to write to database : " + ex.Message);
}
command.Dispose();
```

But I'm a bit stuck when I want to add an unknown count of values in the database (according to a list of unknown size).

e.g. sometimes add only value1, other times add value1, value2 and value3 .... (depending on whats in a certain list).

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I would say the best solution depends on your situation. Here a few practical solutions:
1/ Most obvious solution is to add a child table that contains key/value pair columns.
2/ Another common solution is to add an XML or Json column in your table that contains all the values you want.
3/ If you are not tight to the type of DB you might look for a document database.

Comment: hello, can you elaborate solution 1 and 2 a little bit more? Solution 3 is not an option since it will be a SQL database.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no need for that `SqlDataAdapter`. If you want to add an arbitrary number of values to a table - use a straight `INSERT` `SqlCommand` and just loop over the list of values to insert.

Also: you should **always** use **parametrized queries** - no exceptions - and you should put your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects in `using () { ... }` blocks - something like this:

Something like this:

```
public void InsertValues(List<int> values)
{
    // define the insert query
    string qryInsert = "INSERT INTO dbo.tblTest (value1) VALUES (@singleValue);";
    
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(qryInsert, conn))
    {
        // define parameter
        cmdInsert.Parameter.Add("@singleValue", SqlDbType.Int);
        
        conn.Open();
        
        // loop over values
        foreach (int aValue in values)
        {
            // set the parameter value, execute query
            cmdInsert.Parameters["@singleValue"].Value = aValue;
            cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        
        conn.Close;
    }
}
```